# OVH IPMI applet on Linux

Tags: linux, ovh

Trying to get IPMI from OVH to work on Ubuntu. Getting this error

Error: Could not find or load main class ns102103-ip-147-135-36-us-1.jnlp
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ns102103-ip-147-135-36-us-1.jnlp

Anyone has gotten IPMI applet to work on Linux?

Comment: I think a support case on ovh would sce your issue a bit better imho

Comment: I opened a ticket. Their answer "IPMI works for me. It is fine". The tech basically confirmed IPMI was working on the server and did not address in any way the fact it is crashing on Ubuntu. What is more frustrating is that they indicate in their documentation that the Java client works better on Windows and Linux that on Mac, yet I am at least able to get it to run on Mac and just crashes on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you tried to use `java` to start the JNLP file. JNLP files should be used with Java web start, not the Java executable, like this:

```
javaws ns102103-ip-147-135-36-us-1.jnlp
```

However, Java web start is deprecated, so newer Java version don't contain the executable. The last Java version to have the `javaws` binary is 1.8. Be aware that the licensing of Java has changed, so if you want a freely usable Java VM, you should download a version not newer than 1.8.0_202 (8u202).

Alternatively, you could use a newer OpenJDK and an opensource WebStart implementation like [IcedTea](https://adoptopenjdk.net/icedtea-web.html), however, this approach might lead you to incompatibility issues. Check the requirements of the software first.

Also, you might want to check if there is a browser-only method to access your servers (one which doesn't need any third-party software to be installed). As WebStart is deprecated, I'd be surprised if there wasn't any other means to remote control your computers.

Comment: installed icedtea-netx and that did the trick. OVH applet working.

Answer (score 0):

What browser did you use? Keep in mind that newly versions of chrome, firefox did not support NPAPI, maybe you need additional extensions, or lower version of browser.

Comment: Used Firefox, but the Java applet is downloaded. It doesn't rum from the browser